# how to save code and then calling it in a application

Tags: c#

I have a question, is there a way to somehow save the code you write in some sort of file and call it in to my app? I have started to learn visual C# for a couple of weeks now and I've noticed as I am doing more complex applications the amount of code to write for a single operation is getting out of hand. For example i need to write things like

```
richtextbox1.text ="";
```

for multiple richtextboxes. I don't mind writing a lot of code but I wish I could somehow save it and call it by the file's name so I can be organized and be able to keep track of things. Is there such a way to do this?

example:

```
private void button_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
  do "from the file"
}
```

and that's all i need to write. all help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a Visual C# solution? Then you should add the appropriate tags. Or do you want any solution, no matter what language?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you could have a look at using code snippets. These can be a bit annoying to define (though there are plugins/addons that can help, eg [Snippet Designer](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/)), but very useful when writing code that has common elements. If using Visual Studio 2005/2008, see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2007/12/18/how-to-creating-code-snippets-for-visual-studio-2005-2008.aspx) which links to some examples. If using Visual Studio 2010, have a look [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/code-snippets-visual-studio). Other IDE's probably also support snippets in some form.

A code snippet is a small piece of code that can be modified when you insert it into your file via the IDE. You can do things like click once to add timing code around a block of code, or easily create getters and setters (though most IDEs seem to offer this anyway).

If the code you want to add does exactly what existing code does, I would recommend refactoring, as per Daniel's answer. However if some small part is different, code snippets can be very useful.

Comment: I've done some research on making custom snippets like you said, I see on every tutorial that they use XML to write the snippet and then load it to visual C#. Do you have to create a custom snippet using XML or can you do it directly in visual C#?

Comment: The underlying file will always be XML, but there are plugins such as Snippet Designer that will help you create the snippet file without having to write XML. I don't think you can create snippets directly in code, if that is what you are asking. You should only use snippets if there will be something that you change in each bit of code. Alternatively, you can create a new method that takes parameters to control what to do, and reuse this method. This will minimise code duplication.

Comment: I have another question if you dont mind, can I put my code in some sort of database and call them from there?

Comment: I think it could be done, but I doubt it would be simple or nice. I would highly recomment **NOT** doing that. Creating a new method or class to hold your repeated code would probably be your best bet.

Comment: yeah I guess I'll do that then. Thanks everyone for the help by the way, how do you set this question as answered? or how does this website work? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Would not calling a method be much easier?

Example:

```
private void restTextboxes()
{
  richtextbox1.text = "";
  richtextbox2.text = "";
}

private void button1_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
  resetTextboxes();
}

private void button2_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
  resetTextboxes();
}
```

Comment: Yes it would but, the reason why I want to save a code to a file and then calling it by it's filename is so that my application isn't filled with so much code and easy to navigate you get what I mean?

Comment: @mendez: that's precisely WHY you call another method. It's called re-factoring. And your refactored method can indeed live inside of a separate .cs file if you need it to (look into partial classes).

Comment: In other languages what you're asking for is called a macro, but C# doesn't have them, mainly because their use is considered a bad practice (too easy to abuse).

Comment: @mendez: You can put functions in a separate file and still call those functions by name. One technique for this is to create a `public static class`, which is just a namespace for keeping a bunch of functions together. But you should probably also learn about **object-oriented programming**, which is a technique for organizing code in larger projects.

Comment: Your code would be easy to navigate indeed but the problem would still lie in the dozens of other files. This is strictly the same as putting some of your code in other classes (ie other files) and then using these classes from your main file. You will get the exact same result, without the extra time needed to load a file in memory... What you're asking is how to create a DLL file. But truly, you don't need to go that modular directly.

Comment: Thanks all of you for the help, I needed to know this because my current project is to make a point and click game and coding the transitions between rooms takes a lot of repeated coding based on how I'm programming it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you put your code in other classes. You mention you have too much code in one file. The code in your file should only have something to do with the task. i.e MyApp form should only handle the very basics. Load/save and setting up the rest of the app.

Your code that has nothing to do with user interface you put in a so-called business object so you might reuse them someday.

The different sections in your ui, you put in smaller panels so these small panels will each have a file which will be nice and small. Repeat untill everything is in nice and small files.

That was just the 10k overview. In short a better question would be: how do I put different sections of my ui in userpanels. And how do I design classes with low coupling and high cohesion.